# Jasper Report y C#

Tags: c#, jasper-reports

Tengo una gran pregunta, existe la posibilidad incluir **jasper-report** en **C#**, ya que he buscado por todas partes en Internet y no me brinda una información sobre si se puede usar, he encontrado sobre Crystal report pero no lo puedo usar.

Comment: Jasper Server tiene un api de servicios Rest o Soap que permite consumir reportes hechos con IReport en cualquier tecnología que pueda interactuar con Rest o Soap. Recomiendo buscar la librería adecuada para tu tecnología en github, la cual te va ayudar a comunicarte con JasperServer, montar un ambiente de ejecución de reportes JasperServer y diseñar tus reportes con IReport o JasperStudio

Answer (score 2):

Jasper Reports está hecho en Java y necesita un motor de ejecución sobre Java para ser compilado y generado. [Jaspersoft Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com), la compañía que mantiene a Jasper Reports y tecnologías asociadas, no indica nada respecto al uso de Jasper Reports en tecnologías fuera de la JVM.

Por su parte, quizás necesites investigar sobre soluciones de reportes hechas en C# como Crystal reports. O, podrías crear un pequeño módulo hecho en Java que genere los reportes utilizando Jasper y que llames a este módulo mediante tu aplicación C#, de manera que integras el uso de Jasper a tus aplicaciones C#.

Comment: Gracias Compañero, entonces eso significaria que en vez de usar Jasper Report usaria Crystal report? Ya que usaría C#. Aunque otra solución es esa que me estás dando de de hacer el modulo.

Comment: Correcto. Son ideas. Sería conveniente que tú elijas lo que sea más sencillo para tu contexto.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar como alternativa el Report Viewer de visual studio, es muy fácil de utilizar, te dejo un link de un vídeo donde se explica como utilizar y diseñar tus reportes con c#
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oCXR5VNzPY

espero y te sirva.

Comment: Lo ideal es que uses el espacio para responder para entregar todos los detalles como construir la solución al problema y dejar los links solo como apoyo a tu respuesta, esto porque los links son muy volátiles y el día de mañana en tu caso puede que el video no exista.